# Yet another 'Should I use Core Data' question

Tags: iphone, core-data

I know little about Core Data. Read: I've read a few tutorials, kinda understood how it works, but never tried to use it in any of my apps. That said, I'd like to know if it's worth the effort to use it in the app I'm developing. Note that I'm not asking if *I should learn* Core Data, but if it's worthwhile to invest time learning it for this specific app I'm making, or if I should use archiving instead, ship the app, and only then learn Core Data in my spare time.

Basically my app reads a list of items from a web service, and needs to save the last N items. The user should also be able to bookmark items, so that's another thing I should store somewhere. So, right now I'm just archiving a subarray with range 0-N of the latest items. Does it work? Yes. Is it efficient, and the best way to achieve this? That's my question for you actually.

My doubt comes from the fact that whenever I see someone asking 'Is Core Data overkill for my project?' everyone suggests to use it anyway.

Comment: I personally think it's overkill because you are not using a complex data scheme.  A complex data scheme is Address Book (fields for phone number, name, city, postal code etc...) or Mail (message, subject, to, from). But saying that you could use it if you are using the same fields over and over again and again (two or three fields that are linked together).  It can save you time because of the data model it uses.  So with that in mind, I might need a bit more of an explanation of the app before you or I can make a good decision on weather or not you should use Core Data.

Comment: you're not really describing a specific problem here. whether it's worthwhile or not is subjective or at least very context-dependent. => vote to close, there is no real answer to your question.

Comment: Another important consideration: how big can N get? If your entire object tree can get so big that you cannot comfortably hold it all in memory at once, Core Data with a database backend can be a good idea.

Comment: second the N question: how big is N?

Comment: @Ole Begemann: Yeah, sorry about that. N would be very small, like 10 or 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the amount of data you need to persist can easily fit into memory without degrading the apps performance then you should just archive the array and ship the app.

Core Data gives a lot of advantages when handling large and complex data sets. It gives a lot of advantages in maintaining and upgrading a shipped app. However, those advantages should not get in the way of shipping an otherwise completed app. Later, you can always write code to migrate a shipped version to a Core Data version. It's more work, but hey, at least you've got a shipped app to work on.

I've seen a lot of small startups/developers come and go and the major factor that separates the successful from non-succesful is that the successful actually ship/release product. You can spend forever polishing an app but the key thing is knowing when to say, "It's good enough" and get the thing into the user's hands.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer I needed (especially the last paragraph). Main goal: ship the app. I'll learn about Core Data later.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small  list and you have the data in NSDictionary or NSArray collections, use `writeToFile:atomically:` instead for flat file XML Plist storage.

I still think you should learn Core Data eventually, but.